# Removing table coloumn headers in wicket pageablelistview when list is empty

Tags: wicket

I am using Wicket PageableListView to display a list data. If the data list that is to be displayed inside the table is empty then the table gets rendered with all the column headers and a label in the first.

is there a way to remove those column headers and labels.

I would also like to know how to add "now records found" in a column under column headers and labels (similar to DataTable).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either set the visibility of the entire ListView with setVisiible like this and implementing a custom method shouldListViewBeVisible():

```
    PageableListView plv = new PageableListView() {
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            //populate listitem
        }

        @Override
        protected void onConfigure() {
            setVisible(shouldListViewBeVisible());
        }
    };
```

Or you could try to use the wicket:enclosure tag to make the whole Listview visibiliy dependent on some element within:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket%27s+XHTML+tags#Wicket%27sXHTMLtags-Attributewicket:enclosure

Comment: Hey thg,  i have been experimenting with #onConfiger#setVisible(true) for some time nowand it works only on the columns after header colums. <wicket:enclosure> works for my scenario Thanks a lot